# QlikView RangeSum function computation time

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I would like to us  Qlik ''RangeSum'' function.But for huge data (150000 rows) Rangsum function calculating for long time (more than five minutes) then I must have to stop Qlik and start again.

```
 RangeSum(Above(Sum(Sales), 0, RowNo()))
```

What is the problem? Thank you:-)

[Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svUUN.png)

Comment: Can you upload an image of the data model?

Comment: I am using MS SQL database.

Comment: There is a data model view in qlikview, press Ctrl + T. If you are calculating across several tables or have synthetic keys it will affect the performance.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. You can find the Data Model link above .-)

Comment: You need to provide information about your chart as well. How many dimensions and expressions are you using? Any calculated dimensions? There is a lot of columns in your table, you should remove the ones you are not using. Do you need all the rows or can you limit it with a WHERE clause? For example only load 2 years of data.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

I deleted all extra columns from ms sql table. Now I am using only two columns 'Stock Name' and 'Sales'
Still I am facing same problem with add  expression in straight table 
     RangeSum(Above(Sum(Sales), 0, RowNo()))
Thank you

Comment: Great, that is really strange though. 150k rows should not be a problem. I would try to break it down more to find the problem. Is it possible to attach the qvw?

Comment: @ Thank you mickeger. I try to use another approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that problem is can be in your (probably) small virtual memory, or in bad data model. If you are using for computing some server in company, can be problem on this server...

Answer (score 0):

Encounter the same issue when using rangesum(), and the final calculated rows can be 1000 in the table. Searched a little bit, and the suggestion is not use rangesum() for this kind of calculation, but load it in script first. 
Check more detail from QV community here. 
https://community.qlik.com/message/1185988#1185988

Zhihong